# Производительная приоритетная очередь

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, очередь, поиск-пути

Не мог ли бы кто-нибудь подсказать производительную реализацию приоритетной очереди? В моём случае мне нужно быстрое добавление элементов в очередь и быстрое удаление минимального элемента.

Я нашёл [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761286/8734250), в котором указано, что `hierarchical heap` и `ladder queue` являются наиболее эффективными вариантами, но меня смущает, что я практически не могу найти информацию об этих алгоритмах: про `ladder queue` гуглится одна и та же статья на разных сайтах, а про `hierarchical heap` я вообще ничего не нашёл. Это навевает на меня сомнения.

Comment: А чем вам не нравится стандартная [`priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)? Вы уже попробовали ее, выполнили профилирование и точно знаете, что это именно она тормозит вашу программу?

Comment: @Harry, дело не в том, что стандартная реализация `priority_queue` плоха, а в том, что я человек, двинутый на оптимизации. Я хочу изучить производительные методы и трюки скорее не потому, что мне нужно их реализовать, а потому, что они мне интересны.

Comment: Обычно реализовывают на красно-чёрном или АВЛ дерево.

Comment: hierarchical heap это и есть древовидная иерархия.  Так что комментарии выше вам в помощь

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, но почему тогда `hierarchical heap` выделено отдельно от `AVL tree`?

Comment: AVL tree это частный случай    hierarchical heap

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, здесь определённо что-то не сходится, так как графики `AVL tree` и `hierarchical heap` слишком сильно отличаются. Похоже, будет сложно понять, что имел под `hierarchical heap` создатель диаграммы.